# null object reference on set adapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I know that there are a lot of question like this, but i can't find one that can help me. Please pay no attention at strings that are hard coded or other things like that, i will fix. I don't see anything wrong in adapter class or in the fragments. I use Disco class for fill a place list, the Place class contains all the methods that after i use in the adapter.Can anyone help me please? Thank you.

Class MainActivity

```
package com.techmind.tourguideapp;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ViewPager pager = findViewById(R.id.tourPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new FragmentAdapter(manager));

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
}
}
```

class Disco

```
package com.techmind.tourguideapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Nahuel on 31.05.2018.
 */

public class Disco {

public static ArrayList<Places> initDiscoList(ArrayList<Places> places) {
    places.add(new Places().
            setAddress("via a").
            setImage(1).
            setName("casino").
            setPhone("333").
            setPrice("20€").
            setHour("10:30"));

    return places;
}
}
```

Class DiscoFragment

```
package com.techmind.tourguideapp;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Nahuel on 31.05.2018.
 */

public class DiscoFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ArrayList<Places> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list = Disco.initDiscoList(list);
    PlacesAdapter adapter = new PlacesAdapter(getActivity(), list);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
}
```

Class FragmentAdapter

```
package com.techmind.tourguideapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Nahuel on 31.05.2018.
 */

public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


public FragmentAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new DiscoFragment();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Gradara";
}
}
```

Class Places

```
package com.techmind.tourguideapp;

/**
 * Created by Nahuel on 31.05.2018.
 */

public class Places {

private String name;
private String price;
private String phone;
private String Address;
private String hour;
private int image;
private final int NO_IMAGE = -1;

public Places () {
}

public String getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return Address;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public Places setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}

public Places setHour(String hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
    return this;
}

public Places setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
    return this;
}

public Places setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
    return this;
}

public Places setAddress(String address) {
    Address = address;
    return this;
}

public Places setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
    return this;
}
}
```

Class PlaceAdapter

```
package com.techmind.tourguideapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class PlacesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Places> {

public PlacesAdapter(Context context,  List<Places> places) {
    super(context,-1, places);
}

public View getView (int position, ViewGroup parent, View convertView) {

    View listView = convertView;
    Places place = getItem(position);

    if(listView == null) {
        listView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
    }


    TextView location = listView.findViewById(R.id.locationName);
    location.setText("casino");
    TextView hour = listView.findViewById(R.id.txthour);
    hour.setText("aaa");
    TextView address = listView.findViewById(R.id.address);
    address.setText("aaaaa");
    TextView price = listView.findViewById(R.id.txtmoney);
    price.setText("aaaaa");
    TextView phone = listView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
    phone.setText("aaaaa");
    ImageView img = listView.findViewById(R.id.imgRow);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

    return listView;
}
}
```

Activity_Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.techmind.tourguideapp.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/tourPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

List_item.xml

```
</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_items"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/gradara" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/locationName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text=""/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/positionIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/position"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPosition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/positionIcon"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/positionIcon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/positionIcon"
            android:text="" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/moneyIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/money"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtmoney"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/moneyIcon"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="10€ - 20€" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hourIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/hour"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txthour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/hourIcon"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="09:30 - 23:00" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone:"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3334323560"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You do not have to put your whole code. Post your logcat. Then just put the code associated with your logcat.

Comment: Re, "I know that there are a lot of question like this." If you mean, "questions" that don't contain any actual question, then yes. You're right. You will be more likely to get some help here if you ask an actual question (e.g., "why does my program get this error..." and then you include the actual text of the error message...).

Comment: P.S., if your program is reporting a NullPointerException, then the error message probably tells you from what line of your code the exception was thrown, and from what line the function was called, and with what arguments, etc. There may be enough information right there in the error message to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: plz share logs when posting question instead of posting whole project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the error in

```
ArrayList<Places> list = new ArrayList<>();
list = Disco.initDiscoList(list);
PlacesAdapter adapter = new PlacesAdapter(getActivity(), list);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, container, false);
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_items);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

return view;
}
```

When i use the inflate method the first parameter was wrong, i used the layout of the row instead of the listView layout.

Thank you for your answers, next times i will post logs and less useless code :)

Answer (score 0):

You said you got a null pointer on set adapter.   Are you talking about
this line in file DiscoFragment?

listView.setAdapter(adapter)

if listView is null then the findViewByID didn't find a view.   Or maybe something inside adapter is null.  It is hard to tell from what you said.